# Is this Hack to work around PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS cannot be set to less than one day safe?

Tags: django, security, change-password

Django does not allow the variable PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS to be set to less than one day.

As a workaround, I am thinking of sending the timestamp in the password reset activation URL, using this format:

```
path('activate/<uidb64>/<timestamp>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate')
```

Using the timestamp, I could then manually check whether the timestamp is within a period of time that is less than one day.

Was wondering if doing this is unsafe from a security point of view?

Comment: Why do you expect that to work? The `timestamp` is part of the token by the way.

Comment: The timestamp is part of the token, but I can't extract the timestamp from the token once I recieve it as part of the url.  By sending the timestamp as part of the URL, I can then check when the token was sent, and decide whether to grant access instead of solely relying on Django's binary check_token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Django does not allow the variable `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS` to be set to less than one day.

This issue has been [addressed in Django 3.1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28622). `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS` will be deprecated in favour of `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT` which takes a value in seconds.

In the mean time, you could make your own subclass of [`PasswordResetView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) and provide your own `token_generator` class that does [what Django 3.1 will do](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L8)).

If you want to subclass the existing generator in Django <3.1, [here is the diff](https://github.com/django/django/commit/226ebb17290b604ef29e82fb5c1fbac3594ac163) that shows what you will need to override.

Before you worry about doing this however, it may be worth reading [this note](https://github.com/django/django/commit/45304e444e0d780ceeb5fc03e6761569dfe17ab2) about the security implications of a longer timeout, and checking whether you really need to have a shorter timeout for your purposes.